# what the id mean in the eclipse variables view?

Tags: java, eclipse

In the eclipse variable view, I always see something like

comment "test string"  (id=2559)

what does id=2559 mean? I think it is not the hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats' the unique object-id eclipse assigns to objects it sees.

It helps you in identifying objects while debugging.

Comment: what's the usage for the end user?

Comment: while debugging the same class, you may want to keep track of which objects value is what. Extremely useful in multi-thread environment when multiple threads stop at the break point at same time, and u wan to track which object you are looking in to.