# What is the id=xxx next to variable entries in the Eclipse Debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

What is the `id=xxx` next to variable entries in the Eclipse Debugger> I know it seems to uniquely identify the object. But what I can't tell is what it's relationship to the object is.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java object ID in jvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289550/java-object-id-in-jvm)

Comment: @PetarMinchev Not completely. Your linked question is quite more specific, I think.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [what the id mean in the eclipse variables view?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11060897/716076)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The ID number is arbitrarily assigned by the eclipse debugger, it is just a clue that can help when you are debugging to easily figure out if two variables are pointing to the same object or not ...

Comment: How can I still watching this id (I mean monitoring this object)

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=11426 it looks like it is the JPDA ObjectReference.uniqueId

Answer (score -1):

The `id` field uniquely identifies an object.